# Spring data neo4j: How to append dynamic @Query？

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

How to generate dynamic value of `@Query`  when have complex queries in *Neo4jRepository* ? Like:

```
@Repository
public interface StockRepository extends Neo4jRepository<StockNode,Long> {

     @Query("match (n:stock) where n.name={aShareShortName} return n")
    List<StockNode> getStockNodeByAShareShortName(@Param("aShareShortName") String aShareShortName);

    @Query("match (n:stock) where n.{indexName}={indexContent} return n")
    List<StockNode> getStockNodeByQueryProperty(@Param("indexName")String indexName,String indexContent);

}
```

The  first method `getStockNodeByAShareShortName` is Ok. But the second `getStockNodeByQueryProperty`  is failed. Is there any method to generate dynamic property keys in `n.{xxx}` or `n.?1` or `n.:xx` ?

Answer (score 1):

for creating dynamic property or dynamic query you need to use session(import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;) then you can create dynamic query and append your where condition

String query="match (n:stock) where"  DYNAMIC_FIELD+"=" +VALUE
    session.query(Map.class, query, queryParameters);

Comment: @SunJian If that answer helped, you could mark it as "answer" by clicking the "check mark" next to it.